# Cannot read property of undefied map

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display a json dataset on my localhost browser after getting it with a GET http request from a server.

Code:

```
imports ...
      
  class See extends Component {
      state = { 
         Sessions :[] , 
       }
       

       async componentDidMount(){
           
        const {data: Sessions}= await axios.get("http://localhost:8765/...");
        
        this.setState({Sessions});
    
       }
      render() { 
        
          return ( 
            <React.Fragment>
              <Table striped bordered hover>
                 <thead>
                   <tr> 
                     <th>PointID</th>
                     <th>PointSessions</th>
                     <th>EnergyDelivered</th>
                   </tr>
                 </thead>
                <tbody>
                {this.state.Sessions.SessionsSummaryList.map(Session => (
                   <tr key="Session.PointID">
                   <th>Session.PointID</th>

                   </tr>  
                   ))}
             </tbody>
          </Table>
        </React.Fragment>                            
          );  }
  }
   
  export default See;
```

This dataset consists of some data fields as well  as a list of json object(each one containing 3 fields as shown in Table Headers).

Using the React extention in chrome dev tools i can see that the dataset is loaded in state and is looking like it is supposed to,however i am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

What i also saw with a simple print is that the render method is called 2 times during the run of this code.Is it that the Sessions value is not initialized in the first run?

If yes how can i solve this?

Comment: Can you show what the response of your http request looks like please ? Doing `const {data: Sessions}= await axios.get("http://localhost:8765/...");` means you are extracting `data` which is a typeof Sessions from the result, but then you push `{Sessions}` in your state, which should be `data`.

Comment: @QuentinGrisel {data: Sessions} with this i am taking the data from the http response and store it in sessions

Comment: The first time it runs it won't yet have anything in Sessions, which will still be an empty array. You can initialize to null instead and do `this.state.Sessions && this.state.Sessions.SessionsSummaryList.map`

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the array exits first, destructure and then do the following:

```
const { SessionsSummaryList } = this.state.Sessions || {}; 
 
{ SessionsSummaryList && SessionsSummaryList.map(
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that react is trying to map your object, but that object is not yet filled with data.

I haven't used class based component in a really long time so I just give you the idea of how to do it.

Make a boolean state( sry I write in functional based component, just convert it )

```
const [isFilled, setIsFilled] = useState(false);
```

Now say whenever

> isFilled == true

do this:

```
{this.state.Sessions.SessionsSummaryList.map(Session => (
      <tr key="Session.PointID">
      <th>Session.PointID</th>

       </tr>  
   ))}
```

And whenever you get your data with axios, you have to:

```
axios.get(`XAXAXAXAXAXAXAX`)
      .then(res => {
        setIsFilled(true);
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

As said in others answers, you need to check if your state has the value your are using. In class component, state isn't updated immediately, so you need a condition to verify it. Here is the [repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-functional-boilerplate-16-13-1-6kbzkt) and here is the code :

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";
import "./style.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    user: null
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { data: user } = await axios.get(
      "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
    );

    console.log("user = ", user);

    this.setState({ user });
  }

  render() {
    // Here is the conditions needed to prevent errors when state isn't refreshed yet
    if (!this.state.user) return null;
    return <div>Test = {this.state.user.userId}</div>;
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```